# Is there any google api for tracking no of notification clicked by end user?

Tags: beacon, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I have registered my beacon to google dashboard and configured information in nearby notification API. All works fine... End users receive notification when they entered in specified beacon's location BUT I want to track that how many users click on that notification or not. So Is there any google API to accomplish this?

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a measurement of how many users were *shown* the notification as well as how many *tapped* the notification, yes?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes. exactly